# Why Nautilus is taking too long to load thumbnails in 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04, nautilus, thumbnails

I just fresh installed 18.04.1 yesterday and I'm noticing nautilus is taking significantly long to load thumbnails of files (regardless of their size). Like more than 5-7 minutes. In 16.04, thumbnails loaded in a blink. Running Unity 7 by default.

How to solve this?
I see it's an open bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/1802902

Specs: G4560,16GB DDR4,SSD.
Additional information regarding the problem can be provided upon request.

Comment: did you try to increase thumbnails size in dconf-editor